# How to use a hasChildFilter with JAVA API on ElasticSearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to make a request on geolocation using geoBoundingBowFilter. This is perfectly working. My geolocation have parent-child relation with other object. I'd like to get this object has a response of my geoFilter instead of the geolocation.
I am trying to use the hasChildFilter but my hits in response are always zero.

Here is the code that i am using :

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(index)
                .setTypes(type)
                .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
                .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
                .setPostFilter(FilterBuilders.hasChildFilter("location", FilterBuilders.geoBoundingBoxFilter("point")
                        .topLeft(topLeftLatitude, topLeftLongitude)
                        .bottomRight(bottomRightLatitude, bottomRightLongitude)))
                        .execute()
                        .actionGet();       
return response;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was actually pretty simple, i stopped doing a query.matchall() before my haschildFilter. 
My function is now like that :

```
    SearchResponse response = client
            .prepareSearch(index)
            .setPostFilter( FilterBuilders.hasChildFilter(type,FlterBuilders
                            .geoBoundingBoxFilter("point")
                            .bottomRight(bottomRightLatitude,bottomRightLongitude)
                            .topLeft(topLeftLatitude,topLeftLongitude))).execute()
            .actionGet();
```

I hope it could help some of you.